# Dual monitor graphics card freezing my system

Tags: graphics-card

I bought a second monitor and needed a card that supports dual output. I bought an ATI Radeon x300 128mb on ebay for cheap. It works, but my system freezes A LOT. I know it's the card because when I take it out everything is fine.

I have a Dell Dimension E520 with the RAM upgraded to the max 4gb.

Any idea why my computer doesn't like my card so I can pick a more suitable second one? I don't care about crazy graphics capability, I just want a cheap way to run both monitors.

Thanks, homies.

Comment: Onboard graphics disabled? Do you have the most recent drivers for the device?

Comment: That's a pretty old card.  Was it used?  It may just be defective.

Comment: I think it's obvious why the card was sold on eBay ...

Comment: I got the newest drivers. It's probably just some specific issue my computer has with the card, or the card is messed up. But is it possible to get a card that is too advanced for my computer? Or will anything work that fits in my PCI-E port?